# Where do I find detailed information about the building of programs using boost etc. with the intention of configuring my own API 'protocols'?

Tags: c++, programming-languages, dynamic-programming

I'm brand new to programming in c++ and I'm exploring all the deepest interesting parts on my own, I'm very interested in learning about API programming and how to configure different applications cross programming (between android and windows for example) but I've only found older videos on this subject, I don't mind spending my time digging through online library's to get some PDF's (probably what I'm going to do anyway) that have what I need. But I just wanted to know if anyone else has anything related to this topic. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Ivan, but I'm afraid that *Life Questions* are off-topic. Choosing how to spend your time (books to read, classes to take, projects to construct, career to pursue etc.) may be difficult, but it's specific to you, so unlikely to help future visitors. Questions like this are welcome in [chat] when you have the [privilege](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat). We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, see [ask] & [about].